# Execute a middleware one-time only at server startup in Koa v2

Tags: node.js, middleware, koa, koa2

I created this middleware which executing only once when any route in the website gets the first hit from a visitor:

```js
// pg-promise
const db = require('./db/pgp').db;
const pgp = require('./db/pgp').pgp;

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  try {
    ctx.db = db;
    ctx.pgp = pgp;
  } catch (err) {
    debugErr(`PGP ERROR: ${err.message}` || err);
  }
  await next();
});

// One-Time middleware
// https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2457
const oneTime = (fn) => {
  try {
    let done = false;
    const res = (ctx, next) => {
      if (done === false) {
        fn(ctx, next);
        done = true;
      }
      next();
    };
    return res;
  } catch (err) {
    debugErr(`oneTime ERROR: ${err.message}` || err);
  }
};

const oneTimeQuery = async (ctx) => {
  const result = await ctx.db.proc('version', [], a => a.version);
  debugLog(result);
};

app.use(oneTime(oneTimeQuery));
```

This code executing on the first-time only when a user visiting the website, resulting:

```
app:log Listening on port 3000 +13ms
app:req GET / 200 - 24ms +2s
23:07:15 connect(postgres@postgres)
23:07:15 SELECT * FROM version()
23:07:15 disconnect(postgres@postgres)
app:log PostgreSQL 9.6.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit +125ms
```

My problem is that I want to execute it at the server start, when there's no any visit on the site.

The future purpose of this code will be to check the existence of tables in the database.

**Solution:**

Placing this in `./bin/www` before the `const server = http.createServer(app.callback());` declaration helped:

```js
const query = async () => {
  const db = require('../db/pgp').db;
  const pgp = require('../db/pgp').pgp;
  const result = await db.proc('version', [], a => a.version);
  debugLog(`www: ${result}`);
  pgp.end(); // for immediate app exit, closing the connection pool (synchronous)
};
query();
```

Comment: [pgp.end()](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/module-pg-promise.html#~end) is synchronous, and it doesn't return anything.

Comment: So I have to use without `await`? In my test it's work as it should with or without `await`, without `pgp.end()`, connection pool closed immediately average request time is ~100ms, with `pgp.end()` is about 7-10ms for multiple requests. I know it should sit in a `.finally()` promise block as in your examples, but I try to use your library with `async/await` for better readibility instead of native promises.

Comment: You misunderstand the purpose of `pgp.end`. You should not use it inside an HTTP service at all. It's purpose is to shut down the whole connection pool, and it is for use only within a run-through process to avoid delays in the process exit, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start your application using a js script that requires your app and uses node's native http module to fire up the server. Exactly like in koa-generator ([click](https://github.com/17koa/koa-generator)).

This is in your app.js file:

```
const app = require('koa')();
...
module.exports = app;
```

And then this is in your script to fire up the server:

```
const app = require('./app');
const http = require('http');

[this is the place where you should run your code before server starts]

const server = http.createServer(app.callback());
server.listen(port);
```

Afterwards you start your application with:

```
node [script_name].js
```

Of course keep in mind the async nature of node when doing it this way. What I mean by that - run the 'listen' method on 'server' variable in callback/promise.

Comment: And what does koa-generator got to do with it?

Comment: Thank You, it worked! I actually started the project with koa-generator (creating similar project structure like what express-generator does), but I placed my code in an `app.use` middleware inside `./bin/www`, which for some reason didn't worked. I moved my code out of this and placed in a function, as in my updated question.

Comment: Little thinking about it, `app.use` probably didn't worked, because the server didn't started yet before the server declaration. I know...

Comment: @vitaly-t I thought it might be helpful to provide reference. koa-generator (and basically most generators available) are doing the same thing, which is separating app logic (app.js) from firing up the server (bin/www).